# AUCTeX fails to generate previews

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview, ghostscript

I am trying to generate previews using AUCTeX on Emacs GUI in my tex buffer but I get a "stop" sign error everywhere. See example below:

[image: Error]
When I click on the stop sign and select "View Error" I get the following error message

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/rungs -dOutputFile\=\(_region_.prv/tmpUN6xxH/pr1-4.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r101.002x101.133
GS>{<</PermitFileReading[(_region_.pdf)(_region_.prv/tmpUN6xxH/preview.dsc)]>> setuserparams .locksafe} stopped pop {DELAYSAFER{.setsafe}if}stopped pop/.preview-BP currentpagedevice/BeginPage get dup null eq{pop{pop}bind}if def<</BeginPage{currentpagedevice/PageSize get dup 0 get 1 ne exch 1 get 1 ne or{.preview-BP 0.246098 0.246098 0.246098 setrgbcolor clippath fill 0.859388 0.859388 0.796887 setrgbcolor}{pop}ifelse}bind/PageSize[1 1]>>setpagedevice/preview-do{/.preview-ST[count 4 roll save]def dup length 0 eq{pop}{setpagedevice}{ifelse exec}stopped{handleerror quit}if .preview-ST aload pop restore}bind def /GS_PDF_ProcSet GS_PDF_ProcSet dup maxlength dict copy dup begin/graphicsbeginpage{//graphicsbeginpage exec 0.859388 0.859388 0.796887 3 copy rg RG}bind store end readonly store  (_region_.prv/tmpUN6xxH/preview.dsc)(r)file /.preview-ST 1 index def dup 0 setfileposition 2677()/SubFileDecode filter cvx exec .preview-ST dup dup 5840 setfileposition 54()/SubFileDecode filter cvx<<>>preview-do
Error: /typecheck in --setfileposition--
Operand stack:
   GS_PDF_ProcSet   GS_PDF_ProcSet   GS_PDF_ProcSet   5946   5946   5946   5894   5894   5894   5840
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:742/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 29
GS<10>
```

Additional information that may help:

- I use `Emacs 26.3` (installed with Homebrew on Mac OS X) and I have installed `AUCTeX 12.1.2` through MELPA. I have also installed `ghostscript 9.50` with Homebrew.
- It works fine if I try to compile the TeX file or export the PDF
- I have looked at similar questions from a couple of years ago and it sounds like this was a bug in ghostscript. From reading this question, it sounds like a fix has been added to ghostscript but I still have the error
  ([Can not generate Preview by AUCTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397147/can-not-generate-preview-by-auctex))
- I have also read about modifying the `Preview GS Options` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: Can you please update your AUCTeX to **12.2.0** via ELPA and try it again?

Comment: @ArashEsbati well it turns out it was as simple as that... Looks like it's working fine now, hadn't spotted I hadn't the last version of AUCTeX. I feel a bit silly now! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Preview-LaTeX relies heavily on Ghostscript.  Ghostscript went through some bigger changes lately and Preview-LaTeX now follows these changes with the latest release 12.2.  Currently, the best combination is to update Ghostscript to 9.50 and AUCTeX to 12.2.  The version from ELPA is numbered 12.2.0.